# Maple help needed

Tags: polynomials, maple

Consider the multivariable polynomial
$$g(x,y,z,w)=a_1xyw+a_2xy^2+a_3xyz+a_4x^3z+a_5z^3+a_6y^2z+a_7w^4\;,$$
where $a_1,\cdots, a_7$ are constants. I would like to use Maple to extract the coefficients of all the terms of total degree 3 in the above expression. As a first step, I sorted the terms of the polynomial by total degree, using $>\mbox{sort}(g, '\mbox{tdeg}');$ but then I have no idea how to use coeff to collect the coefficients of interest. Any help is welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Just do the following:

p:="your_polynomial";

vars:=[x,y,z,w];

varset:={op(map(i->op(map(j->op(map(k->i*j*k,vars)),vars)),vars))};

coeffs:=map(i->coeff(p,i),varset);

and you have got everything. There are also powerset methods, but I have no maple here to look them up.

Comment: Upon trying what you suggested, this is what I get: Error, (in unkown) invalid input: coeff received x*w^2, which is not valid for its 2nd argument, x.

Comment: Yes, I see the problem. Maple is shit. You need to replace the last command by this one:
map(i->coeff(coeff(coeff(coeff(expand(p/i),x,0),y,0),z,0),w,0),varset);

Comment: Hmmm. Would it be easier to simply truncate the polynomial to (total) degree 3? I would prefer that, now that I see what Maple's capabilities are. Another thing: how would you extract the coeff of x*w^2, for example? In the final analysis, I would like to know which coefficient goes with which 3rd degree term.

Comment: You can easily save this. I do not know if maple can truncate polynomials, there is this algsubs command, but I really don't know. To save the monomial, do the following command:
map(i->[coeff(coeff(coeff(coeff(expand(p/i),x,0),y,0),z,0),w,0),i],varset);

Answer (score 0):

I would replace each variable x by x*h, then do coeff(f,h,3);

> ```
> f := randpoly([x,y,z],terms=30);
> S := {seq(i=i*h, i=indets(f))};
> g := subs(S, f);
> g := coeff(g, h, 3);
> ```

Then get the coefficients with coeffs.

> ```
> [coeffs(g, indets(g))];
> ```